# Setup color swatches image update (update image without size selection)

Tags: magento2, swatches, color-swatches

is it possible to update the image on colour selection? without having to select size?

I successfully setup swatches, but the image only updates after I select size.

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check this If not, check this  [Guide](http://www.magentech.com/case-studies/item/717-how-to-configure-color-swatches-in-magento-2?) .

Get care of labels and try them on lowercase.

Comment: I am using Magento2, it's very different

Comment: Now check the guide that i give to you.
I saw other webs working perfectly only checking the colour.

Comment: yeah that's a generic guide btw, the problem is different: colour swatches works only after I select size swatch too

Comment: As i see in others webs, only checking a colour, it works.
I will search for more information about this...
Could you provide us a url to check it?

Comment: http://www.hurley.it/it/zoccoli-clogs/zoccolo-corsia.html

Comment: I'm seeing you've got a lot of errors of JS of swatches...
Get this errors out and it will work correctly as other normal demo like this
http://magento2demo.firebearstudio.com/chaz-kangeroo-hoodie.html

Comment: looks like a bug in 2.1.3 this one https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7959 Do you agree? thanks

Comment: It's correct.
Bug on 2.1.3
Sorry mate :)